# PHP String Concatenation (one from variable and another from ternary opeartor) give unexpected results

Tags: php, string

I am describing the problem by example:
let,

```
$actual_food['Food']['name'] = 'Tea';
$actual_food['Food']['s_name'] = 'Local';
```

I am concatenating the aforesaid variables in following way.

```
$food_name = $actual_food['Food']['name']." ".!empty($actual_food['Food']['s_name']) ? "- ".$actual_food['Food']['s_name'] : "";
```

when i print `$food_name` then the output like ' - Local' but does not print  `$actual_food['Food']['name']` content.

I think this question is very little bit silly but my curious mind wants to know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's good to get in the habit of wrapping ternary operators in brackets when concatenating them.

Answer (score 3):

You need to take care about concatenation while using ternary operators. You can try as

```
$food_name = ($actual_food['Food']['name'])." ".(!empty($actual_food['Food']['s_name']) ? "- ".$actual_food['Food']['s_name'] : "");
echo $food_name;// Tea - Local
```

Over here I've enclosed the variables within parenthesis `()`

Its because of what we call [`operator precedence`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). If we don't enclose the ternary operator within parenthesis then your code will be interpreted like as

```
($actual_food['Food']['name'] . " " . !empty($actual_food['Food']['s_name']) ?...;
```

So you simply enclose your ternary operator for correct interpretation

Comment: But why we need to use parenthesis () in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$actual_food['Food']['name'] = 'Tea';
$actual_food['Food']['s_name'] = 'Local';

$food_name = !empty($actual_food['Food']['s_name']) ? $actual_food['Food']['name']." - ".$actual_food['Food']['s_name'] : $actual_food['Food']['name'];

echo $food_name;
```

OR

Add `()` before and after `!empty` condition like

```
 $food_name = $actual_food['Food']['name']." ".(!empty($actual_food['Food']['s_name']) ? "- ".$actual_food['Food']['s_name'] : "");
```